# Best tags to use to draw a legend for a chart in html?

Tags: html

I have a calendar control with various days as various colours.

I want a legend at the bottom, basically three coloured boxes + text

```
X  bibble  Y bibble  Z bibble
```

XYZ are different coloured boxes
I am wondering what a nice way to do this is. Should I dive in with tables, or use divs or some other control with CSS applied? Any elegant solution is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not tabular data, so tables are out. It's not block content, so divs are out.

It's a definition list, so I would use a [`<dl>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_dl.asp) for this.